# Font Style Name for effective search

Tags: fonts, style-identification

I really think I should know this but it is escaping me: what is the style of font where all the of the x-height or is it midline parts of a font match up.

For instance AFPK would have the middle line or junction be the same height. As well as Fa having the top of the a and the middle bar or the F.

Added a visual:
[image: Center line at same height Adso font]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's a name for such a characteristic, but what can help is to look for **Modular fonts**. There are many geometric fonts results.

*Modular* implies that the partitions are equal, so each module is faithfully respected by parts of the letter, like [Matthew Wahl Blocks](http://luc.devroye.org/fonts-52809.html) fonts:

[image]

Adjust the search to *modular sans serif fonts* to get more varied and less structured results like [Veronica](https://njegosh.myportfolio.com/fonts)

[image]
[Black Tulip](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/itc/black-tulip/) from myfonts.com

[image]